# array.join - New variable is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
function sayHello(name1, name2) {
  const joinedNames = sayHello.join(' and ');
  return joinedNames();
}

console.log(joinedNames(['mary', 'john']));
```

GETTING ERROR NOTICE SAYS "Uncaught ReferenceError: joinedNames is not defined"

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: `joinedNames` is defined within the function scope and is not accessible outside of that function.

Comment: I guess you meant `sayHello(['mary', 'john''])`, and `name1.join(' and ')`

Comment: The variable `joinedNames` is in the scope of the function `sayHello` and not in the scope of the console.log

Comment: Thank you ! got it figured out. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a general function like:

```
const sayHello = (...names) => names.join(' and ');
sayHello('Mike', 'Laura', 'Jackie');
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant clearly get what you are trying to do. If you need to join the names of the array,
refer this.

```js
function sayHello(arr) {
  const joinedNames = arr.join(' and ');
  return joinedNames;
}

console.log(sayHello(['mary', 'john']));
```

Comment: Thank You so very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call sayHello not joinedNames. Also you do not need to pass an array when you are using name1 and name2.

```
function sayHello(name1, name2) {
  return [name1, name2].join(' and ');
  }

console.log(sayHello('mary', 'john'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of what I think your script is supposed to do:

```
function sayHello(name1, name2) {
  const joinedNames = [name1, name2].join(' and '); //You want to join the provided names, not the function sayHello
  return joinedNames; //joinedNames is a string, not a function, so you can't call it
}
console.log(sayHello('mary', 'john')); //You want to call the function you defined, joinedNames is just the variable defined within the function
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working and scalable code.

```
function sayHello(name1, name2) {
     var names = [name1, name2];
     const joinedNames = [...names].join(' and ');
           return joinedNames; 
}
     console.log(sayHello('mary', 'john'));
```